# Rerouting model contents using to_param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url, url-rewriting

I am wanting to expand the URLs associated with the contents of a model called `Product`, at the moment, I can view a specific product by going to `products/ID`.

I would like to extend the product URL so it includes some more descriptive information, such as the product name.

I have previously been advised to adjust the `to_param` function (in Product.rb) as below:

```
def to_param
  "#{id}-#{product_name.parameterize}"  
end
```

However, this doesn't currently work.  The URL associated with each product appears correctly when you hover over it / click it, but there is no matching product found.  I get the error `no match for ID=ID-specific-product-name`

If i visit `/products/id` i can still successfully view the specific item

Can anyone guide me as to how I could generate this longer URL containing the product name (`:product_name`)?

EDIT

The `show` controller action in my controller is:

```
def show
@uniqueturbo = Uniqueturbo.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @uniqueturbo }
end
end
```

Comment: Can we take a look at that link code? Also, is everything alright with the `product_name` field in your `Product` AR model?

Comment: Can you show controller action, that gets product from database?

Comment: Thanks for your response @bob, I have added the detail to my question.  Its really strange as the link works fine when I just use ID, but fails when I change to_param

Comment: My understanding was that `find.()` should convert the '/ID-...-....' to an integer, but this no longer seems to work?  The only thing I have done that may affect things is install the `ransack` gem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to make some SEO friendly urls

http://www.yourdomain.com/products/123123-My-Little-PonyBook

- I think that the easiest way is to change the routes, like this

  get '/products/:title/:id' => "products#show"

and then you'll get seo-friendly url's like:

http://www.yourdomain.com/products/My-Little-PonyBook/123123

To generate this url, create helper

```
def url_for_product(product)
  "/products/#{product.title}/#{product.id}"
end
```

- The other way is to leave the normal RESTful route, and reparse 'id' parameter, like:

  ```
  def show
    product_id = params[:id].split('_')[0] # :-)
    # ...
  end
  ```

and still you need the helper method, this time, sth like:

```
def url_for_product(product)
   product_path(product) + "_#{product.title.tableize}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this - I was dubious that it would make any difference as it seemed very similar to what I had before, BUT you're absolutely correct and its fixed the issue immediately!  Would you mind telling me why you used `get '/products/:title/:id' => "products#show"` rather than `match '/products/:title/:id' => "products#show"`?  Thanks a lot for this!

Comment: I think match is being deprecated, anytime soon.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, that's useful to know.  Your code works great